# Error 404.15 Query string too long accessing account/login

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-identity

I'm in the process of moving a ASP.Net web forms app from Membership to Identity. In general, things are working fine, however when I logout, then try to go to the login page, I get Error 404.15 Query string too long. It appears something is repeatedly adding the return url to it.

```
https://localhost:44350/Account/Login?ReturnUrl=%2FAccount%2FLogin%3FReturnUrl%3D%252FAccount%252FLogin%253FReturnUrl%253D%25252FAccount%25252FLogin%25253FReturnUrl%25253D%2525252FAccount%2525252FLogin%2525253FReturnUrl%2525253D%252525252FAccount%252525252FLogin%252525253FReturnUrl%252525253D%25252525252FAccount%25252525252FLogin%25252525253FReturnUrl%25252525253D%2525252525252FAccount%2525252525252FLogin%2525252525253FReturnUrl%2525252525253D%252525252525252FAccount%252525252525252FLogin%252525252525253FReturnUrl%252525252525253D%25252525252525252FAccount%25252525252525252FLogin%25252525252525253FReturnUrl%25252525252525253D%2525252525252525252FAccount%2525252525252525252FLogin%2525252525252525253FReturnUrl%2525252525252525253D%252525252525252525252FAccount%252525252525252525252FLogin%252525252525252525253FReturnUrl%252525252525252525253D%25252525252525252525252FAccount%25252525252525252525252FLogin%25252525252525252525253FReturnUrl%25252525252525252525253D%2525252525252525252525252FAccount%2525252525252525252525252FLogin%2525252525252525252525253FReturnUrl%2525252525252525252525253D%252525252525252525252525252FAccount%252525252525252525252525252FLogin%252525252525252525252525253FReturnUrl%252525252525252525252525253D%25252525252525252525252525252FAccount%25252525252525252525252525252FLogin%25252525252525252525252525253FReturnUrl%25252525252525252525252525253D%2525252525252525252525252525252FAccount%2525252525252525252525252525252FLogin%2525252525252525252525252525253FReturnUrl%2525252525252525252525252525253D%252525252525252525252525252525252FAccount%252525252525252525252525252525252FLogin%252525252525252525252525252525253FReturnUrl%252525252525252525252525252525253D%25252525252525252525252525252525252FAccount%25252525252525252525252525252525252FLogin%25252525252525252525252525252525253FReturnUrl%25252525252525252525252525252525253D%2525252525252525252525252525252525252FAccount%2525252525252525252525252525252525252FLogin%2525252525252525252525252525252525253FReturnUrl%2525252525252525252525252525252525253D%252525252525252525252525252525252525252FAccount%252525252525252525252525252525252525252FLogin
```

In the Account folder, I have the following in the web.config

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<configuration>

    <location path="Login.aspx">
        <system.web>
            <authorization>
                <allow users="*"/>
            </authorization>
        </system.web>
    </location>


    <system.web>
        <authorization>
            <deny users="?"/>
        </authorization>
    </system.web>

</configuration>
```

When I change it to only deny access for specific pages instead of allowing for specific pages, then I don't see this problem, however the app's menu starts showing account management for anonymous users.

Does anybody have any suggestions on how to resolve this?

Comment: The URL has lots of `ReturnUrl=/Account/Login` at various levels of URL encoding suggesting a sort of inifinte loop where the url gets longer and longer until it finally exceeds the maximum request length. The problem is the infinite looping during login. Unfortunately there doesn't appear to be enough information here to figure out what's going on.

Comment: @phuzi yes, but that's the problem. Why are they occurring and how to get rid of them. My not so elegant answer is below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had to do a few things to resolve this. First, to get rid of the 404.15 error, I updated the account folder's web.config file to only deny access to certain pages for anonymous users instead of denying access to the account folder for anonymous users and allowing access to known users where needed. That is

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<configuration>

    <location path="Profile.aspx">
        <system.web>
            <authorization>
                <deny users="?"/>
            </authorization>
        </system.web>
    </location>

</configuration>
```

With that change, a menu item, `PROFILE` was shown for anonymous users when, before it wasn't. To overcome that issue, I now use two different menus, built from site maps. One for anonymous users and the other for authenticated users.

The site map for anonymous users:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<siteMap xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/AspNet/SiteMap-File-1.0" >
    <siteMapNode title="ROOT" description="Root" roles="*">
        <siteMapNode title="HOME" description="Home" roles="*" url="~/" />
        <siteMapNode title="FORUM" description="Forum" roles="*" url="~/forum/" />
        <siteMapNode title="ABOUT" description="About" roles="*" url="~/About" />
    </siteMapNode>
</siteMap>
```

The site map for authenticated users:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<siteMap xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/AspNet/SiteMap-File-1.0" >
    <siteMapNode title="ROOT" description="Root" roles="*">
        <siteMapNode title="HOME" description="Home" roles="*" url="~/" />
        <siteMapNode title="PROFILE" description="Profile" roles="*" url="~/Account/Profile" />
        <siteMapNode title="FORUM" description="Forum" roles="*" url="~/forum/" />
        <siteMapNode title="ABOUT" description="About" roles="*" url="~/About" />
        <siteMapNode title="ADMIN" description="Admin" roles="Administrator" url="~/Admin/Admin" />
    </siteMapNode>
</siteMap>
```

From there, I added both site maps to the web.config file:

```
<system.web>
  <siteMap defaultProvider="MenuSiteMapProvider" enabled="true">
      <providers>
          <add name="MenuSiteMapProvider" description="Default Site Map Provider" type="System.Web.XmlSiteMapProvider" siteMapFile="Menu.sitemap" securityTrimmingEnabled="true" />
          <add name="MemberSiteMapProvider" description="Member Site Map Provider" type="System.Web.XmlSiteMapProvider" siteMapFile="Member.sitemap" securityTrimmingEnabled="true" />
      </providers>
  </siteMap>
</system.web>
```

Finally, I updated the site's master page to use the proper menu for anonymous or authenticated users:

```
Microsoft.Owin.Security.IAuthenticationManager authManager = Request.GetOwinContext().Authentication;
System.Security.Claims.ClaimsPrincipal authUser = authManager.User;
var manager = Context.GetOwinContext().GetUserManager<ApplicationUserManager>();
var user = manager.FindById(authUser.Identity.GetUserId<long>());

MenuSiteMap.Provider = SiteMap.Providers[user == null ? "MenuSiteMapProvider" : "MemberSiteMapProvider"];
```